# MultiAutoCompleteTextView Custom adapter but i m not able to avoid dropdown dismiss

Tags: android

`MultiAutoCompleteTextView` Custom adapter, How to `dismissDropDown` 
my code click listener is not working.

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSq7F.png)

Fragment

```
public class ShareDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{
Dialog dialog;
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
String articleID;
MultiAutoCompleteTextView myMultiAutoCompleteTextView;
TextView Cancel, share;
Context context;
public static ShareDialogFragment fragment;
OnClickListenerCustom onClickListenerCustom;
private PrefManager pref;
ArrayList<ShareWithArticle> userList = new ArrayList<>();

MultiAutoCompleteAdapter adapter;
RequestParse requestParse;
public ShareDialogFragment() {

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.alert_dialog);
    Bundle arg = getArguments();
    if(arg!=null){
        articleID = getArguments().getString("ArticleId");
    }
    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    requestParse = new RequestParse();
    UserNameTo();


}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context = activity;

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_share_dialog, container, false);
    Cancel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Cancel);
    Cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    share = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView22);
    myMultiAutoCompleteTextView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    //ShareWithArticle s = (ShareWithArticle) myMultiAutoCompleteTextView.getAdapter().getItem(position);



    return view;
}
public void UserNameTo(){
    requestParse.postJson(ConfigApi.UserToArticle(), new RequestParse.VolleyCallBackPost() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            userList = ShareArticleuserNameTo.parseResponse(result);

            adapter = new MultiAutoCompleteAdapter(context,R.layout.custom_dropdown, userList);
            myMultiAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
            myMultiAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
            myMultiAutoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown();


        }
        @Override
        public void onRequestError(String errorMessage) {
            M.i("============errorMessage", errorMessage);
        }
        @Override
        public Map OnParam(Map<String, String> params) {
            return null;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.Cancel:
            getDialog().dismiss();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

and My Custom Adapter `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` Code:

```
public class MultiAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShareWithArticle> {
//ShareWithArticle
private final Context mContext;
private final List<ShareWithArticle> mDepartments;
private final List<ShareWithArticle> mDepartments_All;
private final List<ShareWithArticle> mDepartments_Suggestion;
private final int mLayoutResourceId;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
public MultiAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ShareWithArticle> departments) {
    super(context, resource, departments);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mLayoutResourceId = resource;
    this.mDepartments = new ArrayList<>(departments);
    this.mDepartments_All = new ArrayList<>(departments);
    this.mDepartments_Suggestion = new ArrayList<>();
}

public int getCount() {
    return mDepartments.size();
}

public ShareWithArticle getItem(int position) {
    return mDepartments.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }
        ShareWithArticle department = getItem(position);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        ImageView userProfile = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileImages);
        name.setText(department.getUsrFNm() + " " + department.getUsrLNm());


        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
        imageLoader = volleySingleton.getImageLoader();
        requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
        String UsrPrf = department.getUsrPicture();
        RequestParse.loadImages(UsrPrf, userProfile);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}

/*@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return position % 2 == 0 ? false : true;
}*/

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            return ((ShareWithArticle) resultValue).getUsrFNm()+ " " + ((ShareWithArticle) resultValue).getUsrLNm();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint != null) {
                mDepartments_Suggestion.clear();
                for (ShareWithArticle department : mDepartments_All) {
                    if (department.getUsrFNm().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        mDepartments_Suggestion.add(department);
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mDepartments_Suggestion;
                filterResults.count = mDepartments_Suggestion.size();
                return filterResults;
            } else {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mDepartments.clear();
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                // avoids unchecked cast warning when using mDepartments.addAll((ArrayList<Department>) results.values);
                List<?> result = (List<?>) results.values;
                for (Object object : result) {
                    if (object instanceof ShareWithArticle) {
                        mDepartments.add((ShareWithArticle) object);
                    }
                }
            } else if (constraint == null) {
                // no filter, add entire original list back in
                mDepartments.addAll(mDepartments_All);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
}
```